# null when append data to FormData()

Tags: vue.js

I have data structure like this on vue

```
data: {
   name: 'Lorem',
   status: 'Active',
   username: 'user-01',
   password: '12345'
},
```

then I append to `FormData()` because I want to send blob data (image) to the server, like this

```
let formData = new FormData(this.data); // my data
formData.append('photo', this.blob);
```

I use axios, the image are sent but data is not, when I display formData.entries() on console, the result is

```
photo, [object File]
```

How I can solve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rembermer FormData has no Constructor that takes JSON data as an argument.

Try this

```
let formData = new FormData();
for ( var key in data ) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
formData.append('photo', this.blob);
for (var pair of formData2.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```